# large number of page faults after reboot?

Tags: unix, memory-management

This question was asked in a quiz...

After system reboot, you notice vmstat shows large number of page faults as users log on.. This is due to(OPTIONS):

1. Inadequate physical memory that is causing system swapping
2. ECC failures which are being automatically corrected
3. A bad module  in your kernel  or an application that is faulting whenever the bad code is hit
4. Bad memory the kernel blocked from use
5. New processes being loaded into memory by users.

Comment: not a programming question. Also, feels like homework or interview questionaires.

Comment: also, your question could simply be answered by googling page fault.

Comment: did a lot of googling.. couldnt get clue...

Comment: then I don't know what you were looking for. "page fault" has a [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_fault). You must be really bad at using the internet as a source of information.

Comment: this is advanced level question dude.. i know how to use internet, that's why I'm on stack overflow.. what the heck. if you know the answer then post it... otherwise just stop wasting ur and my time please.. :)

Comment: If that quiz you're doing is appropriate for your level of knowledge, understanding what a page fault is once you read the wikipedia page would make answering the question trivial. If you don't understand the wikipedia article, you'll need to read up on some concepts. "Reading up on concepts" is research, and thus, your research abilities are lacking. I think I've given you the decisive pointers, and it's up to you what you do with that -- at least I'm pretty sure I didn't waste your time; maybe I got you a little upset, but that's OK, as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: I already read the wiki page before posting the question. I'm sorry but your reply didn't help me at all.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly these are major page faults - of which [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_fault#Major) says:

> The operating system delays loading parts of the program from disk
>   until the program attempts to use it and the page fault is generated.
>   If the page is not loaded in memory at the time of the fault, then it
>   is called a major or hard page fault.

- or minor page faults - of which [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_fault#Minor) says:

> If the page is loaded in memory at the time the fault is generated,
>   but is not marked in the memory management unit as being loaded in
>   memory, then it is called a minor or soft page fault. The page fault
>   handler in the operating system merely needs to make the entry for
>   that page in the memory management unit point to the page in memory
>   and indicate that the page is loaded in memory; it does not need to
>   read the page into memory. This could happen if the memory is shared
>   by different programs and the page is already brought into memory for
>   other programs.

So, the answer is

> 5. New processes being loaded into memory by users.

You might find e. g. ["Understanding page faults and memory swap-in/outs: when should you worry?"](http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2015/04/10/understanding-page-faults-and-memory-swap-in-outs-when-should-you-worry) instructive.